# iMac: OS X Yosemite - Safari Hijacked by Yahoo

Tags: safari, imac

Today I installed a bittorrent client and it pulled a fast sneaky partnership thing with Yahoo! which swapped my search  homepage and default engine to Yahoo. I'm extremely upset because I despise Yahoo. I've set my search engine in preferences back to Google however,  Yahoo remains. I've checked my extensions and I have no extensions.

I don't have any clue how to revert this back to my default search engine. What can I do?

Comment: Oh and I cleared cookies from the bittorrent website if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have likely installed a Trojan. While there may not be any viruses on OSX that doesn't mean there's no malware.

When you installed / opened the bittorrent client, did you get an admin password popup? If yes, that means something has probably been installed in system space.

What you do to remove it is erase your drive and recover from a backup you made before this happened. No shortcuts allowed - both the visible and hidden system folders as well as your user preferences are now suspect and have to go.

And of course change all your online passwords, today. From a different computer (yours could easily have a keylogger on it now).

Comment: I didn't get A admin password so I'm not sure but thanks for that ill into it.